# New PC applies Windows 10 Update 1709, now wants to install 1703

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

My shiny new PC downloaded and applied Windows 10 Update 1709 (Fall Creator's Update) but  I see update 1703 was queued and now Windows Update wants to install this after installing 1709. Is this correct?

It feels wrong.

Comment: It’s version 1709 and 1703. Let Windows do what it wants to do. It’ll figure it out. There’s not enough information here for us tell you what or why.

Comment: That's helpful @Appleoddity. Thanks. I just needed some reassurance.

Comment: 1073 and 1079 are more than cumulative updates. Seeing they were apparently being queued in this order from available updates is counter-intuitive. I'll trust the process. Also... question got voted down. Really?

Comment: @Dizzley The reason your question got downvoted is likely connected to the fact, Windows 10 Version 1073 and Windows 10 Version 1079 do not exist.  You were told this, and did nothing about it, and now you are just complaining about downvotes.  Your question also is confusing.

Comment: Sorry folks. I got word-blind and once I'd typed the wrong digits I always read them as the correct ones. Again, sorry. I'm going to edit the question for correctness and close the question. I was confused, no wonder other people were.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify:

Windows Update ran on a new PC which was quite out of date. I observed the Fall Creator's Update 1709 download and apparently install itself.

Looking at the release notes, Release 1709 will also cause the downloading and installation of any prerequisite updates before completing its own update. This included release 1703.

Everything turned out fine.